# Pod is built for newer version of

Tags: ios, deployment, cocoapods

After changing both the deployment target of my project and targets from IOS 10.3 to 9.0 I am receiving the following errors. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Error Message]

edit: These errors only show up when running my code in release not debug

Comment: Have you updated the target iOS in your podfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this at the end of your podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There must have been some sort of cache problem I added that code installed the pods deleted the code installed the pods again and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First try cleaning the project (`shift+command+K`). This likely won’t help but is always worth a try.

If/when cleaning does not work, check that the desired iOS version is in `podfile`, and then navigate to the project directory in Terminal and run `pod update`.

Comment: @joshLor, check that the swift version for your pods is the correct one.